# PHP 'Hello World' displays an additional ("; ?>) on a new line but my code appears correct

Tags: php, linux

My Hello World code is:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo "<p>Hello World</p>"; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

The page when ran localhost/test.php loads fine but looks like:

*Hello World*

*"; ?>*

Why would my page be adding the "; ?> my code appears to be correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this really all the code you have?

Comment: Your webserver does not execute the PHP code. Check the source code in your browser.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean there should be an "echo" on the webpage too? @tkausl

Comment: He said its a .php file. The code works fine. Its something else that is going on that you did not mention

Comment: @Andreas no, the Browser sees the whole `<?php echo "<p>` as a HTML-tag.

Comment: The browser is interpreting the open PHP tag as an HTML element, so not displaying anything up until the first `>` - in this case the end of the opening `<p>` tag

Comment: Ahh.. good one! @tkausl

Comment: Yes this is just a test php file before I start working through my tutorials.

Comment: How do I enable php on the server then @tkausl

Comment: There are various reason your PHP code will not be executed. The answer on the possible duplicate enumerates some of the most common ones.

Comment: How did you install the webserver? If you just installed apache2 through your package manager, you need to install `php` and `libapache2-mod-php` aswell. (and enable the mod, i.e. `a2enmod php`)

Comment: One thing that isn't mentioned in that answer is that you'll likely need to restart your web server if you make any changes to its configuration.

Comment: Thank you that worked great I just needed to install libapache2-mod-php @tkausl